# Is the scope of a variable initialized in the arguments of a loop undefined behaviour or implementation defined behaviour in C?

Tags: c, loops, scope, undefined-behavior

for what i know until today, in C, if a loop, for/while has brackets, it has a scope right? i have trying some code in GCC and this appears to be the case, so for example:

```
for(unsigned char i=0;...;...){
   unsigned char j=0;
}
//Outside of the for scope:
unsigned char j=0;
```

Here we have no problem at all, but, what about the variables inside the arguments of a loop?

So for example, this code in GBD C COMPILER (Online):

```
switch(Maneral){
      case 1:
         for(unsigned char i=0x0A;i<=0x64;i=i+0x0A){
            indice++;
         }
      break;
      
      case 2:
         for(unsigned char i=0x0A;i<=0x64;i=i+0x0A){
            indice++;
         }
      break;
   }
```

Gives no error, and i thought that it gives no error because the variables initialized inside the arguments of the for 'share' the scope of the brackets of the respective for

At least that was my headcannon until today because i was programming some embedded code por a MCU using CCS C COMPILER; this compiler says to have '97% ANSI C compatibility', and in this compiler, the next code:

```
switch(Maneral){
      case M_CONICO:
         for(unsigned char i=0x0A;i<=0x64;i=i+0x0A){ unsigned char too=0;
            ActualizaValor(i,DataConico[index]);
            index++;
         }
      break;
      
      case M_CHICO:
         for(unsigned char i=0x0A;i<=0x64;i=i+0x0A){ //LINE 'X'
            ActualizaValor(i,DataChico[index]);
            index++;
         }
      break;
   }
```

Gives an error ont the line 'X' and it says *Identifier is already used in this scope* and for example if i change the "i" in the second for loop for 'j' it gives no error, and for variables declared/defined inside the brackets (and not in the argument of the loop) it has no problem (CCS C COMPILER)

So, the scope of a variable initialized inside the arguments of a loop like 'for()' is something like implementationdefined behaviour / undefined behaviour or it is thing of the *97% ANSI C Compatibility*?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: I know i can just declare/define 'i' outside the switch but i want to understand this beacuse i thought i was sure about what i knew

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of C99, variables declared in the init-clause of a `for` loop are scoped to the entire loop, with its lifetime ending when the loop completes, so the `for` loop roughly behaves as if there was an extra set of implied braces around it, e.g.:

```
for(unsigned char i=0;...;...){
   unsigned char j=0;
}
```

behaves as if you typed:

```
{
   unsigned char i=0;
   for(;...;...){
       unsigned char j=0;
   }
}
```

But this is a C99 (and later) feature, and something claiming "ANSI C compatibility" may be referring to the C89/C90 standard, when this feature of `for` loops was not part of the standard. And in fact, the CCS compiler is using that definition, [as its compliance matrix](https://www.ccsinfo.com/downloads/ansi_compliance.pdf) is defined in terms of ANS/ISO 9899-1990, where the ANSI ISO/IEC 9899-1990 standard is the long official name for the C90 standard.

Comment: Your speculation as to what "ANSI C" means in this context is as good as any but it doesn't match https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_C.  To the different standards bodies are a blur so I figured I would just share the link.  It's not a critique of your answer.

Comment: @AllanWind: Yeah, it can refer to any of the official standards, but as the introduction to that wiki article mentions "Historically, the names referred specifically to the original and best-supported version of the standard (known as C89 or C90)." I've frequently heard "ANSI C" contrasted with C99 and later, not just in casual conversation, but in tutorials, documentation, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!, so according to your answer and the answer from @AllanWind it may be thing of the compiler right? im gonna check if i can change the version of the compiler and see if it is any difference

Comment: Indeed they mean "ANS/ISO 9899-1990" per https://www.ccsinfo.com/downloads/ansi_compliance.pdf.  @ShadowRanger feel free to incorporate the link.

Comment: @CblueX: It could be the compiler, it could be the compiler switches. That is, older compilers often supported the newer standards, but defaulted to C89/C90 (`gcc` defaulted to that, plus GNU extensions, for a *long* time before finally moving the default to `gnu11` in the 5.x line, and then `gnu17` in the 11.x line, all within the past decade, skipping over C99 entirely, having spent over 20 years still using the old C89/C90 standard as the base).

Comment: https://www.ccsinfo.com/downloads/ccs_c_manual.pdf doesn't show any standards flags other than #DEVICE on p. 135.

Comment: @ShadowRanger: Note that if a compiler has any switches that would unconditionally produce some output, a configuration that includes such switches would satisfy the requirement that an implementation produce "at least one diagnostic" when given any program which would not satisfy constraints.

Answer (score 2):

The CCS C COMPILER claims [ANSI/ISO 9899-1990 compliance](http://ccsinfo.com/downloads/ansi_compliance.pdf) where declarations are not allowed in the `for` statement.  I don't see an extension mentioned in their compliance document or 
[CCS C Compiler Manual](https://www.ccsinfo.com/downloads/ccs_c_manual.pdf).

In C 2017 in 6.8.5.3p1 declarations in `for`-loops are scoped as you expected, and if compliant with C 2017 the error would be a compiler bug:

> `for (clause-1; expression-2; expression-3) statement`
>
> [...] If clause-1 is a declaration, the scope of any identifiers it declares
> is the remainder of the declaration and the entire loop, including the other two expressions; it is
> reached in the order of execution before the first evaluation of the controlling expression. If clause-1
> is an expression, it is evaluated as a void expression before the first evaluation of the controlling
> expression.

Comment: I'd go so far as to call it a bug — at least w.r.t. any C standard from C99 onwards.  If the compiler is implementing an extension to C89 (the original ANSI C) without intending to conform to C99, then anything is possible.

Comment: ANSI C89 /  ISO C90 does not allow you to define variables in a `for` loop.  Any support for the notation is an extension over C90.  As I said before, if they don't claim conformance to C99 or later, then their scope rules are permissible as an extension over C90, even though their rules aren't particularly sensible.

Comment: I looked for a bit for the C90 standard and didn't find it.  I will revise as suggested.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Well, the point of declaration of the loop variable is not inside a normal scope, so I can understand a lazy approach like "declared from here on", avoiding too many changes in the compiler. Of course it should be documented.

Comment: Yup, but it has been the non-standard approach for almost a quarter of a century — it would be more sensible to follow the standard, @Peter-ReinstateMonica.  I suppose that in the version in use, `for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) { …1… } for (i = 0; i < n; i++) { …2… }` would work using the first `i` in the second loop.  Fixing the scope to follow C99 would break that — it would either use a shadowed `i` or wouldn't compile.  I don't know how common such code would be.  The OP ran into the converse problem because the compiler doesn't follow the standard.  It's a stupid nightmare either way.